# Javascript execute function in the interval, when mouse is on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, jquery-events

I want to implement a simple thing (mock up here)

```
[+] 123 [-]
```

when user holds mouse on `+` or `-` the sum is increased or decreased.

So I write a simple script to do this (http://jsfiddle.net/wFAfy/3/), seems like it works, but I'm curious about efficiency/robustness of this approach since I'm not very experienced at front-end.

Or is there any better way to do this (maybe using plugins or something)?

HTML:

```
<p id="sum">0<p>
<a id="inc" href="#">inc on hover</a> | 
<a id="dec" href="#">dec on hover</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
sum = $("#sum")
inc = $("#inc")
dec = $("#dec")

currentSum = -> parseInt sum.text()

incSum = -> sum.text currentSum() + 1    
decSum = -> sum.text currentSum() - 1
    
run = (f, direction) ->
  -> 
    return unless running[direction] == true
    f()

running = { inc: false, dec: false }

inc.mouseenter -> running.inc = true
inc.mouseleave -> running.inc = false
dec.mouseenter -> running.dec = true
dec.mouseleave -> running.dec = false

setInterval run(incSum, "inc"), 200
setInterval run(decSum, "dec"), 200
```

Comment: How about the HTML5 `<input type=number scale=1 min=0 max=100>` tag?

Comment: No need to make "inc on hover" and "dec on hover" links.  They can be divs and you can just style them to look like links.  If a user clicks on the links the page will be reloaded.

Comment: Instead of always having 2 `setInterval`s always running and checking a flag, execute the `setInterval` on `mouseenter`, and execute a `clearInterval` on `mouseleave`

Comment: @Lowkase, sorry, in actual app I have styled divs for inc/dec buttons. I was just trying to simplify demo.

Comment: @lan, thank you, I didn't know about `clearInterval`. this is nice improvement

Comment: @evfwcqcg No problem! Yeah, I think by using my suggestion, it will cut down on processing since there stuff is only running when it needs to be. Also, it should be more precise, since it's not guaranteed that the `setInterval` code picks up exactly when you mouseover the element. It will be incredibly close (and probably unnoticeable) since you're using an interval of 200ms, but could be a problem if you increased that value. I don't know coffeescript, otherwise I'd provide an example of what I mean. Would a basic Javascript example help?

Comment: @lan yeah sure, any example would be very helpful :)

Comment: @evfwcqcg Something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/3t4nc/1/

Comment: @lan, great, this really helped me a lot. I would be happy accept this as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Ian's suggestion - here is a sample of that implementation:

```
$sum = $ '#sum'
$inc = $ '#inc'
$dec = $ '#dec'

currentSum = 0

incSum = -> $sum.text currentSum++
decSum = -> $sum.text currentSum--

interval = null

$inc.on
  'mouseenter' : ->
    interval = setInterval incSum, 200
    incSum()
  'mouseleave' : -> clearInterval interval

$dec.on
  'mouseenter' : ->
    interval = setInterval decSum, 200
    decSum()
  'mouseleave' : -> clearInterval interval
```